# Android - Download and Save File within AsyncTask

Tags: android

I am wanting to download an APK file from an URL inside the AsyncTask.

The getFilesDir() method is not currently available inside the AsyncTask as it does not have the context.

I'm currently setting the file directory path inside the onCreate() method of the activity and then accessing this class member variable within the AsyncTask - however this feels like a hack and I'm unsure of the correct implementation to avoid memory leaks.

```
public class UpdateAppActivity extends Activity implements ConfirmationDialogListener
{
    private String mAPKFileDirectory;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        mAPKFileDirectory = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        ...
    }

    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) 
    {
        APKUpdater apkUpdater = new APKUpdater
        apkUpdater.execute();       
    }

    private class APKUpdater extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean>
    {
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            ...
            downloadAPK();
        }

        public Boolean downloadAPK()
        {
            ...

            File file = new File(mAPKFileDirectory);
            file.mkdirs();          
            File outputFile = new File(file, "update.apk");

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager).

Comment: Is is perfectly ok to give a path as variable to an asynctask. You should even execute mkdirs() before calling the async task. Only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist an check its return value.

Comment: Thanks, what if the activity is destroyed, wouldn't that cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid memory leak you can make `APKUpdater` class static and pass path to execute function:

```
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) 
{
    APKUpdater apkUpdater = new APKUpdater
    apkUpdater.execute(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());       
}


private static class APKUpdater extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean>
{
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        ...
        downloadAPK(params[0]);
    }

    public Boolean downloadAPK(String path)
    {
        ...

        File file = new File(path);
        file.mkdirs();          
        File outputFile = new File(file, "update.apk");

        ...
    }
}
```

Or use [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) as @Martin Zeitler mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, could you advise on why making the class static avoids a memory leak? Sorry if it's obvious but I'm quite new to Android/Java. I've also seen an approach using a WeakReference to the file directory path, should this be avoided / last resort?

Comment: In java inner classes hold implicit reference to outer class, in our case it's activity. Making inner class static removes this reference. You don't need to wrap file directory path in WeakReference because it's not the cause of memory leak.

Comment: Thank you - I'm getting any error message with passing in getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()

error: constructor APKUpdater in class UpdateAppActivity.APKUpdater cannot be applied to given types;

required: no arguments

found: String

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: I've spotted my error - I was calling APKUpdater apkUpdater= new APKUpdater(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()); instead of apkUpdater.execute(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()); - Thank you, appreciate the help

Comment: I've hit another problem within the AsyncTask - I now need to run FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authority, file) so that I can open the APK installer - however this requires the context - is a weak reference required for this?

Comment: Yes, you need to use WeakReferene to store reference to activity or use something like this https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Rotation/RotationAsync/src/com/commonsware/android/rotation/async/RotationAsync.java